# Four vector potential and discrete parity transformations

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, field-theory, gauge-theory, parity

I am having trouble understanding the effect of parity transformations on the four-vector gauge field (for example). I am working in three dimensions, but the analysis is probably not that different from that of four dimensions. In [this](https://www-sciencedirect-com.ezproxy.library.uwa.edu.au/science/article/pii/S0003491600960135) paper (pg 4) they have the following written down,
\begin{align}
\mathscr{P}A^0(t,\textbf{r})\mathscr{P}^{-1}&=A^0(t,\mathbf{r}')\\
\mathscr{P}A^1(t,\textbf{r})\mathscr{P}^{-1}&=-A^1(t,\mathbf{r}') \tag{1}\\
\mathscr{P}A^2(t,\textbf{r})\mathscr{P}^{-1}&=A^2(t,\mathbf{r}')
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\mathscr{P}=\begin{pmatrix}
1&&0&&0\\0&&-1&&0\\0&&0&&1
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
is the parity operator in $2+1$ dimensions. What do the above statements mean and how can I derive them? I think it is something symbolic, because if I take the second one for example, then I have $\mathscr{P}A^1(t,\textbf{r})\mathscr{P}^{-1}=A^1(t,\textbf{r})\mathscr{P}\mathscr{P}^{-1}=A^1(t,\textbf{r})$. So clearly this isn't how it is supposed to be interpretted. If I look at the usual way a unitary transformation corresponding to a Poincare transformation acts on a scalar field (since each component $A^a$ is scalar), 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{U}(\Lambda,b)\phi(x)\mathcal{U}^{-1}(\Lambda,b)=\phi(\Lambda^{-1}(x-b))
\end{align}
and set $b=0$ and $\Lambda=\mathscr{P}$ then I get
\begin{align}
\mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P})\phi(x)\mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P}^{-1})=\phi(\mathscr{P}^{-1}x).
\end{align}
If I now replace $\phi(x)$ with $A^1(t,\mathbf{r})$ i get
\begin{align}
\mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P})A^1(t,\mathbf{r})\mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P}^{-1})=A^1(t,-x^1,x^2).
\end{align}
Am I allowed to bring out this minus sign from the argument? (aka are these linear functions?). But even then it wouldn't give me $-A^1(t,\mathbf{r}')$.

What if I try to do all of the components at once? The unitary operators act on vector fields by 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{U}(\Lambda,b)A^a(x)\mathcal{U}^{-1}(\Lambda,b)&=\Lambda^a_{~b}A^b(\Lambda^{-1}(x-b))\\
\implies  \mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P})A^a(x)\mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P}^{-1})&=\mathscr{P}^a_{~b}A^b(\mathscr{P}^{-1}x). \tag{2}
\end{align}
Looking at the components of (2) gives
\begin{align}
\mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P})A^0(x)\mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P}^{-1})&=A^0(\mathscr{P}^{-1}x)\\
\mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P})A^1(x)\mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P}^{-1})&=-A^1(\mathscr{P}^{-1}x)\\
\mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P})A^2(x)\mathcal{U}(\mathscr{P}^{-1})&=A^2(\mathscr{P}^{-1}x).
\end{align}
Now these expressions are looking much closer to those given in (1), however there are a few differences. First of all, the arguments of the field are different, on the righthand side I have used the inverse whilst they have used just $\mathscr{P}x$, which leads me to believe that the arguments of my formula (2) are the wrong way around?  Secondly, on the LHS they have $\mathscr{P}A\mathscr{P}^{-1}$ whilst I have the corresponding unitary operators.... I thought they were supposed to be acting on the Hilbert space (and hence could be infinite dimensional reps)? Is this just shorthand for what I have written? What about the case of time reversal when it is supposed to be represented by an antiunitary operator?

Comment: $\mathscr{P}^{-1} = \mathscr{P}$, thus you don't have a sign discrepancy

Comment: Of course..... Thank you. Do you think that when they say $\mathscr{P}$ they are referring to the unitary operator which implements the parity transformation on the Hilbert space?

Comment: Yes I think so. Physicists use the same symbol for a group element and its representation as a kind of shorthand when no confusion is likely to arise.

Comment: well thats ironic...